# How to dynamically use chartjs-plugin-annotation with ng2-charts?

Tags: angular, ionic3, chart.js, ng2-charts, viewchild

I'm creating a statistic page where I need to display several charts, I made a DynamicChartComponent which covers the bar- and line-chart from the demo here(https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/#DynamicChart). 
One of the charts needs to display an average annotation of the datasets. For this I'm using the chartjs-plugin-annotation which is configured as following:

```
{
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{}],
      yAxes: [
        {
          id: 'y-axis-0',
          position: 'left',
        }
      ]
    },
    annotation: {
        drawTime: "afterDatasetsDraw",
        annotations: [
            {
            type: 'line',
            mode: 'horizontal',
            scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
            value: 0, // Average must be filled here
            borderColor: 'red',
            borderWidth: 2
            },
        ]
    },
}
```

Unlike the dataset values, the annotation doesn't update when the value is changed, so I tried to manually update the chart by using the ViewChield decorator.

DynamicChartComponent.ts:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { DynamicChart } from '../../libs/classes/dynamicChart';
import { ChartDataSets, ChartOptions, ChartType } from 'chart.js';
import { Label, BaseChartDirective } from 'ng2-charts';
import * as pluginAnnotations from 'chartjs-plugin-annotation';

@Component({
  selector: 'dynamic-chart',
  templateUrl: 'dynamic-chart.html'
})
export class DynamicChartComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(BaseChartDirective) chart: BaseChartDirective;

  private mychart = new DynamicChart();

  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit(){
    console.log("_chart", this.chart);
  }
  setAnnotation(value){
    this.mychart.options.annotation.annotations[0].value = value;
    //this.chart.update()
  }
```

inside DynamicChartComponent.html

```
<canvas baseChart *ngIf="datasets"
    [datasets]="datasets" 
    labels]="labels"
    [chartType]="chartType"
    [legend]="legendVisible"
    [options]="options"
</canvas>
```

Expected usage on statistic page:

```
private myDynamicChart = new DynamicChartComponent();
myDynamicChart.setAnnotation(averageValue);
myDynamicChart.update();
```

I found out that the ViewChild decorator produces the error:

```
Object(...) is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong here?

The answers from other questions mention the use of ng2-charts-x, but that didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I have a similar issue - I am adding annotations at runtime, but they do not update.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this today and solved it by calling:

```
this.chart.ngOnChanges({});
```

instead of

```
this.chart.update()
```

The ngOnChanges call causes the chart to update and display the annotations I added programmatically whereas when calling update, they would not show at all.  Hopefully this helps anyone who stumbles on this issue going forward.